# What is the equivalent of AVRCP for Bluetooth low energy?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, headphones

Exactly what is the equivalent of that profile(AVRCP) that I can implement on BLE device? Remember the control unit on a Bluetooth headphone(play/pause, next/previous)? My goal is to make that control unit using BLE. The sound is still coming out from the phone, no headphone required. More like a remote control for music player in android phone.

Comment: you want to control your Music App or just any Android Music App?

Comment: Mine, a simple music app that can play any file with .mp3 extension from SD. Basic control such as play/pause and next/previous is enough.

Comment: Then you can just define your own commands in the app and have the device send these commands.should be easy

Comment: Hey how about accepting the one answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent. You will need to define a custom GATT service with the commands you need.